# Why does it save only one row of data from arduino on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to save data from Arduino to a text file on my raspberry pi 2 using USB. The code works, but only saves the first line with data from arduino. I have to multiple open (in terminal) my script so it will add more lines. How do i make it to add more like until i open it?

```
#!import serial
saveFile = open('log.txt','a')
set = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
serData = ser.readline()
saveFile.write('\n')
saveFile.write(serData)
saveFile.close()
```

Comment: Why to you expect your code to read more than one line when you use `readline()`?

Comment: Hm... good point. How should i modify to see more lines? I'm new to python sorry. Should i make a loop? (I tryed that with no result)

Comment: Serial should have a readlines function I think.

Comment: Using readlines leaves my text file empty

Comment: Please explain what "tried that with no result" means exactly - edit the code you used and the result you got to your question. Also, please define how you would want to mark the end of the file, because either you will have to have some special marker indicating that the file ends, or send the length of the file before sending the content, otherwise you would have your program listen for new data infinitely.